# Bar graph rotation in Androidplot orientation sensor

Tags: java, android, androidplot

I am having difficulty attempting to rotate the Levels plot in the Orientation Sensor example, by 90 degrees such that the bar graph is pointing towards (or away from) the history plot.

I have tried the `android:orientation=""` in the `xml file` but with no positive result.

It does not seem to be down to simply a matter of swapping X and Y as the bar has to start from a different edge.

In my own code, I have replaced:-
`SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY` with
`SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.XY_VALS_INTERLEAVED` as I am actually plotting a `Histogram` rather than a `Single bar` in the java file.

However I am unable to effectively rotate this plot (the history plot needs to remain as it is.)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
Androidplot 1.3.1 has been released with added support for rotating the graph widget:

xml:

```
ap:graphRotation="ninety_degrees"
```

java

```
plot.getGraph().setRotation(Widget.Rotation.NINETY_DEGREES);
```

Unless you're using them, you'll also want to disable the domain/range cursor (normally hidden behind the origin lines):

```
plot.getGraph().setDomainCursorPaint(null);
plot.getGraph().setRangeCursorPaint(null);
```

**Original answer (for anyone not yet on 1.3.1):**

It's not directly supported today but could be added pretty easily.

For now, you can achieve the basic effect by rotating the canvas 90 degrees before each render cycle and restoring afterwards.  This will work flawlessly if your plot space happens to be perfectly square.  Otherwise, the canvas' immuatable height and width would need to be transposed to account for the altered aspect ratio, which may be possible but probably is not worth the headache involved.

Here's a quick and dirty way to rotate a plot:

```
 plot.addListener(new PlotListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBeforeDraw(Plot source, Canvas canvas) {
                    final float h = canvas.getHeight()/2;
                    final float w = canvas.getWidth()/2;                
                    canvas.save();
                    canvas.rotate(90, w, h);

                @Override
                public void onAfterDraw(Plot source, Canvas canvas) {
                    canvas.restore();
                }
    });*/
```

All of this approach's shortcomings can be resolved by instead extending XYGraphWidget and overriding doOnDraw(Canvas, RectF), since there we can mutate the RectF as needed. It's quite a bit more work though to wire the new instance back into the XYPlot and re-apply xml attrs to the widget.

Comment: I've updated my answer now that support has been added to 1.3.1

Comment: Thanks for adding this Nick

Comment: Thanks for adding this Nick. I tried the XML solution. It works well. However is it possible to rotate 270 degrees ( or -90 degrees). At the moment the rotated plot in my app is inverted. Thanks again  Dean

Comment: Yep; just change `NINETY_DEGREES` to `NEGATIVE_NINETY_DEGREES`.

Comment: Thanks once again,  I am now almost there !! Having rotated the plot counter clockwise the scale values that used to be at the bottom are now upside down and on a 45 degree slant any suggestions? From your orientation sensor example code I would also like to totally remove the Domain (slant line colour bars) is this possible also? Thanks

Comment: When you rotate the graph, you'll also need to account for that in any styles etc. you apply to that plot.  To rotate the domain labels in xml so that they appear correct in this orientation: `ap:lineLabelRotationBottom="180"` As far as the "slant line colour bars" - I'm not certain which element you're referring to.  In any case it sounds like a separate issue so I'd suggest creating a new question along with a screenshot highlighting the element you're wanting to hide/remove.

Comment: Using ap:lineLabelRotationBottom="90" resolved the issue. Where can I find a comprehensive listing of ap: ...instructions? The line label is centred on the axis line of the plot. is there a margin type command to offset the line labels? I will however create a separate question fro the hiding of the other element as you suggested.

Comment: Currently, the only comprehensive list is the project's [attrs.xml](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml)  It can be a little hard to directly derive the meaning of these attrs however, so it might be easier to take a look at how the [default androidplot styles](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/style.xml) make use of them instead.

Comment: I have only just noticed that the setRotation feature adds a yellow grid bar.  this can be seen in the OrientationSensorExampleActivity.java         if you insert  "aprLevelsPlot.getGraph().setRotation(Widget.Rotation.NEGATIVE_NINETY_DEGREES);"

Comment: I wanted to add a screenshot but the Ctrl + I function doesn't seem to work. It is not only the Negative rotation.

Comment: That sounds like the domain/range cursor.  I'll update my answer with code to disable the cursor.